# how to extract text from a pdf-like bytes array?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf

I am currently working on raw email, specifically email that contain pdf attachments. when i parse my email, i got the attachment formatted as bytes array class which look approximately like this:

```
b'%PDF-1.4\n1 0 obj\n<<\n/Creator (Oracle11gR1 AS Reports Services)\n/CreationDate (D:20171013070840)\n/ModDate (D:20171013070840)\n/Producer (Oracle PDF driver)\n/Title (LHV1708766_5B690D8A8B350700E0530A0087619F5D.pdf)\n/Author (Oracle Reports)\n>>\nendobj\n5 0 obj\n<</Length 6 0 R\n/Filter
```

which contain a lot of weird characters etc etc..

My question is how can i extract only the "plaintext" from this bytes array ? usually, i use the textract lib to extract text, but it can't take string or bytes array as parameter (only pathlike or filename)

Thanks